# 'We' vs 'I' on website for app

Tags: websites

I'm not really sure where to ask this, but I'd like this question to be approached from a business perspective so I figured let's go here.

Suppose I develop an app, as a single developer.

Now I make a website for the app.

On the website should I use "We" or "I" to refer to myself. For example, should I say "I truly believe in Open-Source" or "We truly believe in Open-Source"?

I feel like if I registered a company behind the app, I should use "We", otherwise "I".

Now I haven't registered a company (yet) but I still would like to use "We" but would that make sense or should I stick to "I" in that case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is probably better on the User Experience Stack.

Comment: Im not really sure where it fits best but maybe a mod can migrate it ... ?

Comment: This might be better for the English Language and Usage SE.

Comment: Generally, large corporations try to appear like mom and pop shops. And mom and pop shops or solo endeavours try to appear like they're large corporations. Personally, I think that's all BS. Be authentic. Be yourself. If you're one-man shop, don't try to make it like you're not. Also, people are much more likely to give you leeway in their reviews if they believe you're a solo developer.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That's true I suppose, people will be more lenient on a solo dev. But to the possible detriment that people will also potentially have less confidence in the abilities of that solo guy.

Comment: @csstudent1418, Is your icon professional-grade? What about the design of the app or the screenshots? Because if you say you're a company, but don't behave like one. It's going to lower people's confidence in your app even more. Personally, I just think you should play to your strength. Tell the truth. Be authentic. It's going to be a lot cheaper. And believe me, people such as myself, that have worked for large corporations, know that they're not as efficient or as magical as everyone thinks they are. And given a choice, many of us would rather invest in a solo developer, not in a company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either, but 'we' is usually preferable unless you're making a point that it's a solo project. It makes it seem that there's more to it than someone whipping things together in their garage.

If it's on behalf of a company, then use the company name and 'we'.

eg. 'At ACME Limited we're committed to incorporating roadrunner safety protocols into our nuclear warheads'

Comment: -> [Pluralis Majestatis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we) ;)